# ConcurrentQueue in a ConcurrentDictionary Duplicate Error

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, concurrentdictionary

I have a thread that handles the message receiving *every 10 seconds* and have another one write these messages to the database *every minute*.
Each message has a different sender which is named `serialNumber` in my case.

Therefore, I created a ConcurrentDictionary like below.

```
public ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConcurrentQueue<PacketModel>> _dicAllPackets;
```

The key of the dictionary is `serialNumber` and the value is the collection of 1-minute messages. **The reason I want to** collect a minute of data is instead of going database every 10 seconds is go once in every minute so I can reduce the process by 1/6 times.

```
public class ShotManager
    {
        private const int SLEEP_THREAD_FOR_FILE_LIST_DB_SHOOTER = 25000;
        private bool ACTIVE_FILE_DB_SHOOT_THREAD = false;
        private List<Devices> _devices = new List<Devices>();
        public ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConcurrentQueue<PacketModel>> _dicAllPackets;

        public ShotManager()
        {
            ACTIVE_FILE_DB_SHOOT_THREAD = Utility.GetAppSettings("AppConfig", "0", "ACTIVE_LIST_DB_SHOOT") == "1";
            init();
        }
        private void init()
        {
            using (iotemplaridbContext dbContext = new iotemplaridbContext())
                _devices = (from d in dbContext.Devices select d).ToList();

            if (_dicAllPackets is null)
                _dicAllPackets = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConcurrentQueue<PacketModel>>();

            foreach (var device in _devices)
            {
                if(!_dicAllPackets.ContainsKey(device.SerialNumber))
                    _dicAllPackets.TryAdd(device.SerialNumber, new ConcurrentQueue<PacketModel> { });
            }
        }
        public void Spinner()
        {
            while (ACTIVE_FILE_DB_SHOOT_THREAD)
            {
                try
                {
                    Parallel.ForEach(_dicAllPackets, devicePacket =>
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(100);
                        readAndShot(devicePacket);
                    });
                    Thread.Sleep(SLEEP_THREAD_FOR_FILE_LIST_DB_SHOOTER);
                    //init();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //init();
                    tLogger.EXC("Spinner exception for write...", ex);
                }
            }
        }
        public void EnqueueObjectToQueue(string serialNumber, PacketModel model)
        {
            if (_dicAllPackets != null)
            {
                if (!_dicAllPackets.ContainsKey(serialNumber))
                    _dicAllPackets.TryAdd(serialNumber, new ConcurrentQueue<PacketModel> { });
                else
                    _dicAllPackets[serialNumber].Enqueue(model);
            }
        }
        private void readAndShot(KeyValuePair<string, ConcurrentQueue<PacketModel>> keyValuePair)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            if (keyValuePair.Value.Count() <= 0)
            {
                return;
            }
            sb.AppendLine($"INSERT INTO ......) VALUES(");
//the reason why I don't use while(TryDequeue(out ..)){..} is there's constantly enqueue to this dictionary, so the thread will be occupied with a single device for so long
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                keyValuePair.Value.TryDequeue(out PacketModel packet);
                if (packet != null)
                {
                    /*
                     *** do something and fill the sb...
                     */
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No packet found! For Device: " + keyValuePair.Key);
                    break;
                }
            }
            insertIntoDB(sb.ToString()[..(sb.Length - 5)] + ";");
        }
    }
```

`EnqueueObjectToQueue` caller is from a different class like below.

```
private void packetToDictionary(string serialNumber, string jsonPacket, string messageTimeStamp)
{
            PacketModel model = new PacketModel {
                MachineData = jsonPacket, 
                DataInsertedAt = messageTimeStamp
            };
            _shotManager.EnqueueObjectToQueue(serialNumber, model);
}
```

How I call the above function is from the handler function itself.

```
private void messageReceiveHandler(object sender, MessageReceviedEventArgs e){
   //do something...parse from e and call the func
   string jsonPacket = ""; //something parsed from e 
   string serialNumber = ""; //something parsed from e
   string message_timestamp = DateTime.Now().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => packetToDictionary(serialNumber, str, message_timestamp));
}
```

The problem is sometimes some packets are enqueued under the wrong `serialNumber` or repeat itself(duplicate entry).

Is it clever to use `ConcurrentQueue` in a `ConcurrentDictionary` like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not a good idea to use a `ConcurrentDictionary` with nested `ConcurrentQueue`s as values. It's impossible to update atomically this structure. Take this for example:

```
if (!_dicAllPackets.ContainsKey(serialNumber))
    _dicAllPackets.TryAdd(serialNumber, new ConcurrentQueue<PacketModel> { });
else
    _dicAllPackets[serialNumber].Enqueue(model);
```

This little piece of code is riddled with race conditions. A thread that is running this code can be intercepted by another thread at any point between the `ContainsKey`, `TryAdd`, the `[]` indexer and the `Enqueue` invocations, altering the state of the structure, and invalidating the conditions on which the correctness of the current thread's work is based.

A `ConcurrentDictionary` is a good idea when you have a simple `Dictionary` that contains immutable values, you want to use it concurrently, and using a `lock` around each access could potentially create significant contention. You can read more about this here: [When should I use ConcurrentDictionary and Dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42013226/when-should-i-use-concurrentdictionary-and-dictionary)

My suggestion is to switch to a simple `Dictionary<string, Queue<PacketModel>>`, and synchronize it with a `lock`. If you are careful and you avoid doing anything irrelevant while holding the lock, the lock will be released so quickly that rarely other threads will be blocked by it. Use the lock just to protect the reading and updating of a specific entry of the structure, and nothing else.

#### Alternative designs

A `ConcurrentDictionary<string, Queue<PacketModel>>` structure might be a good option, under the condition that you never removed queues from the dictionary. Otherwise there is still space for race conditions to occur. You should use exclusively the [GetOrAdd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.getoradd) method to get or add atomically a queue in the dictionary, and also use always the `queue` itself as a locker before doing anything with it (either reading or writing):

```
Queue<PacketModel> queue = _dicAllPackets
    .GetOrAdd(serialNumber, _ => new Queue<PacketModel>());
lock (queue)
{
    queue.Enqueue(model);
}
```

Using a `ConcurrentDictionary<string, ImmutableQueue<PacketModel>>` is also possible because in this case the value of the `ConcurrentDictionary` is immutable, and you won't need to `lock` anything. You'll need to use always the [`AddOrUpdate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.addorupdate) method, in order to update the dictionary with a single call, as an atomic operation.

```
_dicAllPackets.AddOrUpdate
(
    serialNumber,
    key => ImmutableQueue.Create<PacketModel>(model),
    (key, queue) => queue.Enqueue(model)
);
```

The `queue.Enqueue(model)` call inside the `updateValueFactory` delegate does not mutate the queue. Instead it creates a new [`ImmutableQueue<PacketModel>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablequeue-1) and discards the previous one. The immutable collections are not very efficient in general. But if your goal is to minimize the contention between threads, at the cost of increasing the work that each thread has to do, then you might find them useful.

Comment: Appreciate your feedback. I understand and agree with going with a simple `Dictionary` and `lock`ing it instead of a `Concurrent` one ever since the dictionary keys are also not changing so often it will not affect the performance. But I need to enqueue and dequeue with the multithreading. I can't go with the normal queue if I lock that also is going to be very slow.

Comment: @TaylanYuksel are you sure that it's slow? The cost of an uncontested `lock` is less than 10 nsec in a modern machine, and the combined cost of getting a value from the `Dictionary` and then enqueuing/dequeuing something from a `Queue` should be way less than 1 μsec on average. Unless you are expecting to do hundreds of thousands of operations per second, I would not expect to see significant contention.

Comment: I assumed that It will be slow since multithread accessing. Yes, I am expecting more than a hundred messages per second. Isn't the purpose of the `Concurrentqueue` to avoid using `lock`s in multithreading? I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3548196/15213512) that suggests `concurrent` instead of `lock`ing in which similar case to mine.

Comment: @TaylanYuksel I updated the question with a couple of alternative designs.

Comment: Btw if you use the `lock` correctly, locking hundreds or thousands times per second should not generate noticeable contention. I would expect to see non-negligible contention at around 100,000 locks per second or more.